# Computing distribution (joint probability given)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with a joint cumulative distribution function.

Also, $X$ and $Y$ are absolutely continuous, positive and independent.

The joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ is

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{\alpha \beta}{x^{(\alpha+1)}y^{(\beta+1)}}1_{x,y \geq 1}$

How to compute the distributions of $X$ and $Y$?

I tried this:

Since the probability density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is given, I integrated partially and I got:

$F_X(x,y)=-\frac{\beta y^{- \beta-1}}{x^\alpha}+C$ for the distribution of $X$ and

$F_Y(x,y)=-\frac{\alpha x^{-\alpha-1}}{y^\beta}+C$ for the distribution of $Y$.

I'm not sure if this works.

Is this way to determine the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution  If you are familiar with the Pareto distribution, you can immediately figure out that the joint pdf is the product of two Pareto pdf. To find the marginal distribution, you just integrate out the other variable, say $f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$